# Valgrind memory leak caused by calloc

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm new to C and I've been having a hard time tracking the issue with the memory loss in a dynamically allocated 2d array of int in the following simple code snippet:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define ROW  2    /* initial number of rows  */
#define COL   3     /* initial number of cols*/

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

size_t initial_row = ROW;
size_t initial_col = COL;
size_t new_col = 30;

/*allocate initial 2d array of ints*/
int **arr = NULL;
arr = calloc( initial_row, sizeof(*arr));

for (size_t i = 0; i < initial_row; i++) {
    arr[i] = calloc(initial_col, sizeof(*(arr[i])));
}

/*populate the array*/
for (size_t i = 0; i < initial_row; i++) {
    memset(*(arr + i), 0, initial_col * sizeof(**arr));

    for (size_t j = 0; j < new_col; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = 11;

        if ((j + 1) == initial_col) {

            void *temp = realloc(arr[i], 2 * initial_col * sizeof(int));
            if (temp) {
                for (size_t k = i; k < initial_row; k++) {
                    arr[k] = temp;
                    memset(*(arr + k), 0, initial_col * sizeof(**arr));
                }
            }
            initial_col *= 2;
        }
    }
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < initial_row; i++) {
    free(arr[i]);
}
free(arr);

return 0;
}
```

The summary by valgrind:

```
==626974== HEAP SUMMARY:
==626974==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==626974==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 4,496 bytes allocated
==626974== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==626974==    at 0x4C306B5: calloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==626974==    by 0x40078C: main (Untitled-1.c:30)
==626974==
==626974== LEAK SUMMARY:
==626974==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==626974==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==626974==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==626974==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==626974==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==626974==
==626974== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==626974==
==626974== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==626974== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==626974==    at 0x4C2F50B: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==626974==    by 0x400993: main (Untitled-1.c:80)
==626974==  Address 0x51f72e0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 192 free'd
==626974==    at 0x4C2F50B: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==626974==    by 0x400993: main (Untitled-1.c:80)
==626974==  Block was alloc'd at
==626974==    at 0x4C308BF: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==626974==    by 0x400880: main (Untitled-1.c:51)
==626974==
==626974== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Apparently, the error is caused by

```
arr[i] = calloc(initial_col, sizeof(*(arr[i])));
```

but I can't wrap my head around the reason for it. I understand, however, that I lost the memory allocated for exactly 3 integers (one call by `calloc( initial_row, sizeof(*arr))` ). But the thing is that I free the pointer to every row allocated. I would highly appreciate any pointers (haha) to help me spot my error!

**EDIT**: the problem was with allocating one chunk of memory and assigning the pointer to it to all the subsequent rows after the one reallocated. This led then to multiple frees. The issue was fixed by allocating memory for each row separately.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do after the `realloc`?

Comment: This is a very rough example of assigning values to a reallocated row of the 2d array to understand the memory management in C. I first initialize the array to have 2 rows and 3 columns but then resize each row to incorporate 30 cells/columns. I then assign each of the cells of the 2x30 used space to '11' (just as an example!) and free the pointers in the end.

Comment: You're assigning the realloced memory to multiple rows, which leads to a memory leak and double-frees.

Comment: Could I ask you to elaborate? Do I understand it correctly that I basically use the same pointer for all the rows, following the one reallocated? Would it be a better strategy to reallocate each row separately?

Comment: @KristinaPianykh You should, once and once only, allocate some memory for each row.

Comment: Just fixed this and it works now flawlessly! Thank you so very much for the help!!